# should jQuery data be chainable?

Tags: jquery, chaining

I'm trying to add multiple jQuery data entries to a single element.

I suspected that the following would work

```
jQuery('td.person#a'+personId).data('email',thisPerson.email).data('phone',thisPerson.phone);
```

However, I am getting nothing but errors when I do this.

```
jQuery('td.person#a'+personId).data('email',thisPerson.email);
jQuery('td.person#a'+personId).data('phone',thisPerson.phone);
```

is there another way to get more than one data entry on an element? Hopefully chained?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass an object into [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), like this (broken so to prevent horizontal scroll)

```
jQuery('td.person#a'+personId)
      .data({email:thisPerson.email, phone:thisPerson.phone});
```

To answer your question though, **yes** it should be chainable, if you post what errors you were getting that would help see why it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll move it to an object. The error I'm getting in firebug really doesn't provide any data other than 'jQuery(